# SQL SERVER Table Valued Parameters (Table Type) in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Type Multi-Valued Parameters passed to SP
Can you use TVP within WHERE clause in a SELECT query?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ProductCategoryId IN @tvpCategories
```

I mean, instead of a sub-query (example as below) can we use TVP?

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ProductCategoryId IN (SELECT Id from ProductCategories)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, you can: `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ProductCategoryId IN (SELECT Id from @tvpCategories)`

Comment: But treat it as another table.  So you have to select the required fields from it for you IN clause.

Comment: *It's a table.* Join to it.

Comment: SELECT PRODUCTS.* 
FROM @tvpCategories categories 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS on PRODUCTS .ProductCategoryId = categories.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like :

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ProductCategoryId IN (SELECT Id from @tvpCategories)
```

Table value param are in table, for programming you can consider them as temp table stored in memory till execution scope is completed.

Answer (score 2):

IF you do not want to use a subquery, then a join would be another option.

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.* 
FROM @tvpCategories categories 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS on PRODUCTS.ProductCategoryId = categories.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a table valued parameter is just like using a table variable except for the fact that table valued parameters are readonly.

This means that you can either use a sub query with the `in` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE ProductCategoryId IN (SELECT Id from @tvpCategories)
```

Or use a join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTS 
INNER JOIN @tvpCategories tvp ON ProductCategoryId = tvp.Id
```